# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'TITLE' of 'dotenv.parsed' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, npm-start

when i npm run dev i take that error :

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'TITLE' of 'dotenv.parsed' as it is undefined.
```

here is my webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path'),
  HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
  ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin'),
  ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin'),
  { merge } = require('webpack-merge'),
  dotenv = require('dotenv').config(),
  devConfig = require('./config/webpack.dev.config'),
  prodConfig = require('./config/webpack.prod.config');

const APP_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'src');
const DIST_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'dist');
const TEMPLETE_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'public', 'index.html');
const { TITLE } = dotenv.parsed;

baseConfig = {...
..
.
```

that error occurs in 13th line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this error is implying is that the `TITLE` prop isn't present in the `dotenv.parsed` object. One way to avoid *getting* the error, is to attempt this: `const title = dotenv?.parsed?.TITLE;` and then asserting whether the `title` variable holds a value different than `undefined`.

On another note, without further examples, I'm not able to assess why the `dotenv.parsed` object doesn't indeed contain the `TITLE` prop. If this was your initial concern, please provide your `dotenv` file contents (with care, please).

Comment: thanks a lot. my issue is solved by adding `const title = dotenv?.parsed?.TITLE;`